# SSRS Report for MS CRM 2011 - Page Break

Tags: reporting-services, report, crm

I have created a report which contains textboxes. The textboxes are set directly on the report body.

Now I want to create a second page for that report, exaclty same as the first one. How can I add a page break or create the second page some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add second page then add a rectangle after the first page contents.
Now after adding the Rectangle, go to the rectangle properties by clicking right click on it and select "Add a page break after".
Now below the rectangle you can put your second page contents or text-boxes.

In same way you can create as many pages as you want.